# Unable to install Keycloak Angular 15.2

Tags: angular, keycloak

Unable to install Keycloak  in Angular (v15.2) using npm. But able to install **keycloak-js**

```
npm install keycloak-angular keycloak-js
```

Getting this Error!!! Any specific version need to be used?[image]